# Using Android Studio, how can I create a value which will increase its value by 1 every time a button is clicked?

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on an app for a project in University and am seeking to find out how to increase a variable value by 1 when a button is clicked. The app I am building is a sports app, and my idea is that when a button titled "Goal" is pressed that the value of "Goal" will be increased by 1.

I am also going to be putting this information into a Firebase real-time database so if you have any knowledge on how I could also do this would be very helpful. Thanks very much.

Comment: Please, explain what you have already tried or investigated. There are many tutorials and books out there that explain what you need. You should check https://developer.android.com/training/index.html and also https://codelabs.developers.google.com/?cat=Android (one of the tutorials is about Firebase).

Comment: look into this http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/10/how-to-increase-integer-value-when-button-is-clicked.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a button to your .xml file like this :

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Goal"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:onClick="add1ForTeamA"
    android:id="@+id/Three_Button_B"/>
```

then if you will notice that the android:onclick has been set to the add1ForTeamA method. Go to the mainActivity.java file and add this method

```
`public void addOneForTeamA(View view) {
    scoreTeamA = scoreTeamA + 1;
    displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
}`
public void displayForTeamA(int score) {
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Team_A_Score);
    scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(scoreTeamA));
```

Comment: also make the id whatever, i changed my code to be relavent to your assignment and didn't change the @+id.

Comment: can you vote this as an answer to your query

Comment: No problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do that is to have an integer variable into your Activity called maybe "goal" that is initialized to 0 by the OnCreate(). Then you create an OnClickListner to be attached to the button so that will call a function to increment the variable value every time the button is pressed.